# Error while execute arangod 3.2 in centos 6.9

Tags: linux, centos6, arangodb, foxx

I try to execute arangodb 3.2 (version updated) in my server centos 6.9 but don't work, what I can do for fixing it?.

```
[root@user ~]# arangod
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] INFO ArangoDB 3.2.1 [linux] 64bit, using jemalloc, VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.0.0, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips        11 Feb 2013
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] INFO using storage engine mmfiles
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] INFO {cluster} Starting up with role SINGLE
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] INFO {syscall} file-descriptors (nofiles) hard limit is 8192, soft limit is 8192
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] INFO Authentication is turned on (system only), authentication for unix sockets is turned on
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] ERROR error while opening database collections: got invalid indexes for collection '_fishbowl' (exception location: /var/lib/otherjenkins/workspace/RELEASE__BuildPackages/arangod/MMFiles/MMFilesCollection.cpp:2004). Please report this error to arangodb.com
2017-08-18T20:01:34Z [8419] FATAL cannot start database: got invalid indexes for collection '_fishbowl' (exception location: /var/lib/otherjenkins/workspace/RELEASE__BuildPackages/arangod/MMFiles/MMFilesCollection.cpp:2004). Please report this error to arangodb.com
```

Comment: I suggest to file a bug which is what the logfile suggests: " Please report this error to arangodb.com"